# Does there exist a robust Twilio enabled CMS with subscription management?

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce, subscription, twilio

I've done quite a bit of searching for a CMS platform or robust framework that will perhaps facilitate the management of signup and subscriptions right of the box with a Twilio tie in.

Thus far I've only been successful at finding how many startups have been funded by the Twilio fund, who's building the nextgen voice enabled app, and various other things of that nature vs any real meat.  Seems that there's a dearth of meaningful information without applying a plethora of negative google filters to reduce matches and even then it's still not giving anything real meaningful wrt my search.

So, I'm hoping that someone may have a better eye on the lay of the Twilio landscape as far as already existent systems go that can handle the bulk of needs that exist for a "regular" CMS esque site that needs to also handle subscriptions and e-commerce related tasks.

Hitherto I've just planned to build something out myself, but I wanted to do a sanity check before I spend a lot of time that could perhaps be obviated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to find a CMS that does everything you want (except the twilio links), on the platform you want, and then just add the [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) stuff in. Twilio is *simple* to use, and should be simple to add-on to most open source CMS's. It'll probably be the easiest part of the project....

Comment: Appreciate the input.  Ruby on Rails with Hobo it is then.  I've been so hesitant to just flesh it all out myself with so many things being done, but there's no real solid contender for a Rails CMS right now vs php ones, so I might as well just bite the bullet and build out the feature set I need in something with which I feel comfortable.

Comment: I don't know of the ones in the Rails space but in PHP, Drupal is the leading contender as far as I can find. There are two modules of note - SMS Framework and VoIP Drupal - that integrate with Twilio to varying degrees. I'm working with VoIP Drupal right now and it's pretty handy, though only compatible with D6 currently.